# How to add redirect button for details into auto populate Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, button, gridview

```
    public DataSet Bind()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from games where type='rpg', con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (!object.Equals(ds, null))
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

The system will call this function at PageLoad(), it will populate the GridView.

I want to add a button on each row so the user can click on the button and goes into the item details.

Any solution can done it?

Answer (score 0):

I will give one example ...your doubt will be very clear...

**.aspx Page**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTesting" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="98%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Number">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTest" runat="server" Text='<% # Bind("Test") %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("Test") %>'
                            OnClick="lnkTest_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<% # Bind("Id") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**.aspx.cs Page**

```
 protected void lnkTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent;
        HiddenField hdnId = (HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("hdnId");

    if(Convert.ToString(hdnId.value)=="1")
    {
            Response.Redirect("frmTest1.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }

    else if(Convert.ToString(hdnId.value)=="2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmTest2.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmTest.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }
    }
```

**Note:-**

In Page Load,you have to bind GridView(as per your Prefrence..)

Suppose,You have a Gridview with Link Button(which redirect to different Pages...)

So, you have to also bind Id........so can Redirect to Different Pages as Per your ID...

On click of link button you can redirect to other page(as per your Logic..) with sending Query string value(Id)

Comment: The link button bind test, what is the "test" ?

Comment: ...That u want bind the gridview in page load....Or u can say column name that you want to bind...

Comment: @@Eason...that bind the gridview using dataset i.e. ds.Tables[0]...it contain some column name....that you want bind the gridview....here i'm assuming the column name as Test....as Column Name...

Comment: The problem is here I have 2 column which is the gameName...one is populated from gridview which do not have any redirect, other one is generated from your code. Is that anyway to mix them together?

Comment: I think you to use Merge both the Table.....follow this link...it will help u...https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b182bf/how-to-add-two-datatable-in-single-datatable-in-C-Sharp/